# Netbeans Plugin Develpment

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-8

I need to work on a Netbeans Addon for self for a programming language. The plugin should support following:

- Code Completition
- Syntax Highlighting
- Project Template(eg: PHP Project Type)

I did find something related to code completition [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html) but not getting clue of others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For syntax highlighting: http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR

Project templates: https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-povray-4.html

(both links could be found via the search on the Netbeans website itself)